# Problemas com Inner Join e sub-query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Essa minha query abaixo serve para montar uma tabela com dados de multiplas tabelas, porém está dando um erro:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row 0.000 sec

Eu acho que e o problema é nessa sub-query:

```
(select tblCategoria.nomeCategoria as nomeCategoria 
   from tblAnimeHentai 
  inner join tblCategoria on tblAnimeHentai.categoria = tblCategoria.idCategoria) as categoria
```

Acho que ele carrega todas as categorias em vez de carregar a correspondente.

```
select tblAnimeHentai.nomeAnime           as nomeAnime
      ,tblAnimeHentai.descricaoAnime      as descricaoAnime
      ,tblAnimeHentai.episodiosAnime      as episodiosAnime
      ,tblAnimeHentai.tumbLocation        as tumbLocation
      ,(select tblCategoria.nomeCategoria as nomeCategoria 
          from tblAnimeHentai 
         inner join tblCategoria on tblAnimeHentai.categoria = tblCategoria.idCategoria) as categoria
      ,tblAnimeHentai.completo            as completo
      ,tblAnimeHentai.dataPublicacao      as dataPublicacao
      ,tblAnimeHentai.dataAdicionado      as dataAdicionado
      ,tblAnimeHentai.comentarioAnime     as comentarioAnime
      ,tblAnimeHentai.produtora           as produtora 
  from tblAnimeHentai;
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Como posso corrigir o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o que precisa é uma subquery correlacionada, tente:

```
(select tblCategoria.nomeCategoria as nomeCategoria from tblCategoria where tblAnimeHentai.categoria = tblCategoria.idCategoria) as categoria,
```

Quanto a sua outra dúvida:

```
SELECT
    tblAnimeHentai.nomeAnime as nomeAnime, 
    tblAnimeHentai.descricaoAnime as descricaoAnime, 
    tblAnimeHentai.episodiosAnime as episodiosAnime,
    tblAnimeHentai.tumbLocation as tumbLocation, 
    (SELECT tblCategoria.nomeCategoria as nomeCategoria FROM tblCategoria WHERE tblAnimeHentai.categoria = tblCategoria.idCategoria) as categoria,
    tblAnimeHentai.completo as completo, 
    tblAnimeHentai.dataPublicacao as dataPublicacao, 
    tblAnimeHentai.dataAdicionado as dataAdicionado, 
    tblAnimeHentai.comentarioAnime as comentarioAnime,
    tblAnimeHentai.produtora as produtora 
FROM tblAnimeHentai
WHERE tblAnimeHentai.categoria = "categoria x";
```

Comment: Outra dúvida, como eu colocaria um where no final de categoria, tipo where categoria = "categoria x"

Comment: no caso, a tblAnime.categoria é um int, eu quero informar a categoria com texto, tipo, tblAnime.categoria = 1, enquanto tblCategoria.catgeoria = "categoria x", eu quero fazer o select por meio do texto gerado com o join